# how to calculate the lift value of table in R?`

Tags: r, table-functions

```
library(readr)
data1<-read_csv(".../file1")
data2<-read_csv(".../file2")
table2<-table(data1$`_SEGMENT_`,data2$`_SEGMENT_`,data1$Subscribed)
```

This is the frequency `table2` I created with three variables, data1 segment as row, data2 segment as column and third dimension 'Subscribed' with `'yes'` and `'no'`.

```
> table2
, ,  = no

   
       1    2    3    4    5
  1   29  674 5189 7207   88
  2    3  194 1393 2166   39
  3   18  471 2667 5719   77
  4    0    1    2   11    0
  5   18  420 2798 4715   88

, ,  = yes

   
       1    2    3    4    5
  1    0   33  262 1000    1
  2    0   10   65  322    0
  3    0   25  190 1206    2
  4    0    0    1    3    0
  5    0   26  166  943    3
```

How to create a lift value table of 'yes' based on `table2?` 5x5 table and each position value = value of `'yes'`/(value of `'yes'`+value of `'no'`)

e.g. `table_liftvalue[1,2] = 33/(33+674)`

```
> table_liftvalue

       1    2    3    4    5
  1   . 33/(674+33)
  2   .
  3   .
  4   .
  5   .
```

I appreciate any help.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1w6mj.png

Comment: Can you include `dput(data1)` and `dput(data2)` in your post so that it becomes reproducible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `apply` for the `sum`, then just divide.

```
table2[,,"yes"]/(apply(table2, 1:2, sum))
#      [,1]       [,2]       [,3]      [,4]       [,5]
# [1,]    0 0.04667610 0.04806458 0.1218472 0.01123596
# [2,]    0 0.04901961 0.04458162 0.1294212 0.00000000
# [3,]    0 0.05040323 0.06650333 0.1741516 0.02531646
# [4,]  NaN 0.00000000 0.33333333 0.2142857        NaN
# [5,]    0 0.05829596 0.05600540 0.1666667 0.03296703
```

---

*Data:*

```
table2 <- structure(c(29L, 3L, 18L, 0L, 18L, 674L, 194L, 471L, 1L, 420L, 
5189L, 1393L, 2667L, 2L, 2798L, 7207L, 2166L, 5719L, 11L, 4715L, 
88L, 39L, 77L, 0L, 88L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 33L, 10L, 25L, 0L, 
26L, 262L, 65L, 190L, 1L, 166L, 1000L, 322L, 1206L, 3L, 943L, 
1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 3L), .Dim = c(5L, 5L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
    NULL, c("no", "yes")))
```